# Unsupported Media Type from multi part file api

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, project-reactor

It is always giving 415 unsupported media type in error from POSTMAN. Header contains multipart/form-data with boundary as in CURL call below. Also tried replacing RequestPart with RequestBody without success.

Do we need to call multi part file upload apis from spring 5 in any different way when using FilePart instead ?

RESTContoller :

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void uploads(@RequestPart("filePart") Flux<Part> fileparts) {

     ....

}
```

Curl :

```
curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8080/upload \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'postman-token: 2e850843-13d0-32d3-8734-227242da3303' \
  -F filePart=@abc.txt
```

Output:

```
"status": 415,
"error": "Unsupported Media Type",
"message": "Content type 'text/plain' not supported",
```

**EDIT**

Changing uploads argument from `@RequestPart("filePart") Flux<Part> fileparts` to `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file` however works.

Can't we use same curl call with RequestPart ?

Comment: Is it a requirement to use the `Flux` api?

Comment: @Niver, with Flux<Part> we can process files while its uploading. So this is not a requirement but I suppose it should work anyway with Flux as well ?

Comment: As it is a new introduction in Spring 5 I was asking myself if there can be any issue with the way you are using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to pom.xml having both spring-webmvc and spring-webflux added as dependency. It seems `spring-webmvc` and `spring-webflux` can't be enabled together.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux`  dependency in my pom.xml .
So when I  used `spring.main.web-application-type=reactive` in application.properties . It works  fine for me .